# Good resources to practice in determining if a series is convergent or divergent!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if anyone have any could recommendations on resources where I can practice on questions ns such as determine if this series is convergent/divergent etc.. Or have any good problems in this area for a math undergraduate ( I am not looking for easy questions, I would like it to be challenging but still doable using basic knowledge of Abel's test, root ratio test etc( or maybe just knowledge of the first few chapters of Rudin's book) and the questions must not be straightforward application of such techniques( requires you to think ) ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 10 of this free online text http://scidiv.bellevuecollege.edu/dh/Calculus_all/Calculus_all.html has been very nice for me. It goes section by section with all the different types of tests, and has tons of practice problems for finding if series converge or diverge, using tests discussed in the current section.